# How to properly redirect a url to the exist-db port

Tags: apache, exist-db

In apache virtual host I attempted to redirect `/db` to the exist database. This works only momentarily such that it shows the exist welcome screen but then exist redirects to the dashboard and that page is not found.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /db http:**localhost:8899
ProxyPassReverse /db http:**localhost:8899
```

I'd like to set things up so I can do REST queries like `/db/rest`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some URL rewriting and cookie handling: the following example maps "/" and "myapp2". It is possible to map to /rest/db/myapp1 too.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyRequests       off
        ServerName      myserver

        ProxyPass         /myapp2/ http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/myapp2/
        ProxyPassReverse  /myapp2/ http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/myapp2/

        ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/myapp1/
        ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/myapp1/

        ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost myserver
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath   /         /exist

        RewriteEngine       on
        RewriteRule         ^/(.*)$     /$1   [PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! In my case the interesting thing is `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /exist` does not work but  `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /exist /` works! However, with this configuration I can’t access via **REST**, other parts of the app work well.